# uidocumentinteractioncontroller open in mail do not work

Tags: ios

I use uidocumentinteractioncontroller in my app , but I found that, if I do not set a mail account for mail, when I click mail in Open In menu ,it just dismiss,do not have a alert or something to tell me,that I do not have a mail account.
  Maybe I can show alert by myself ,if I know the iphone do not have mail account,I can show alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- check if the user has email account

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if (mailClass != nil)
    {
        if ([mailClass canSendMail])
        {
            // show the email dialog
        }
        else
        {
            [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
    }
```

2- Here is the LaunchEmailAppOndevice

```
+ (void)launchMailAppOnDevice {

    NSString *recipients = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?subject=%@",kEmailToAddress,kEmailSubject];
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&body=%@", kEmailBody];
    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

When you call LaunchMailOnDevice the user will be asked to enter new account, and then your message will be generated automatically

Comment: Thank for you answer any way,launchMailAppOnDevice work well,but it can use not in uidocumentinteractioncontroller,or is there any way to check mail account without open mail app.

Comment: I haven`t used MessageUI.framework before,I get it ,it`s a good answer.Just use canSendMail is fine.

Comment: Yes @Roy, you need to check first if the user has account using canSendMail to show UIDocumentationInteractionController, if the user has no account then you can use launchMailAppOnDevice

Comment: O，do you know any way to check if I click mail button in UIDocumentationInteractionController?

Comment: Check UIDocumentInteractionController delegate methods for this. – documentInteractionController:willBeginSendingToApplication:
– documentInteractionController:didEndSendingToApplication:
The "application" parameter should have something that might help. Cheerz

Comment: I tried, click mail didn`t call the delegate methods.